# How do I find xpath for "Invalid License!" text in the HTML code shown

Tags: xpath

```html
<div id="content" class="content">
<div class="container col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button class="close" aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Invalid License!</strong>
```

Please provide xpath for above code. I am not able to find xpath.

Comment: Can you add trials done by you or exception you are facing ?

Answer (score 3):

You've got several options.

The simplest and most obvious (assuming there are no other `<strong>` elements on the page with the text "Invalid License!") is `//strong[text() = "Invalid License!"]`

If that fails, I'd start with `//div[id = "content"]/div/div/strong[text()="Invalid License!"]`

If that proves impossible, I'd try finding the button, going to its parent div, then looking within that div for the `<strong>` tag.

(Caveat: I am not an xpath expert - this is more of a guide to finding the element you need than completely accurate advice)

Comment: I am not sure that if #1 would fail there is even a chance to be successful with #2 because #1 includes all the objects including the one that could be returned by query #2.

Comment: You're likely correct, @AlexeyR. but if the combination of the tag and text is repeated on the page, then query #2 or method 3 would be needed.